# Div height 100% but non resizable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a div which covers my page entirely but when I resize my browser window I do not want the div to be resizable. In other words this 100% height should not refers to the actually window size but to the max window size.

I want to calculate the browser window max height and I want my div to have that height. It should be a fixed height so that if I resize my window should appear a scrollbar which make me scroll the content

For example: if you visit this website http://weareflourish.com/ its main page has a div with a background which covers the page entirely (even if you visit the website with different resolution). I want to reproduce the same effect

Comment: i don't understand what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what's the url? This isn't totally clear.

Comment: Can you provide the source code? We can't help you if we can't see your problem

Comment: A URL and/or code would be helpful, especially since I'm not sure your requirement is necessary. While you may resize your browser all over the place in testing, it's very rare for users to resize their browser during visiting sessions.

Comment: See the website I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with pure css.

You have three different values:

1. screen resolution (fixed)
2. browser dimensions (dynamic)
3. viewport dimensions (dynamic)

You cannot rely on the screen resolution because you cannot guarantee, that this is the actual size of your viewport. If you instead rely on browser or viewport dimensions you are stuck with a dynamic size which changes on browser resize.

The only thing you can do is determine the viewport size via javascript and set the div to this specific size. This way it won't change on viewport resizes.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("#yourElement"),
height = window.innerHeight, width = window.innerWidth;

div.style.height = `${height}px`;
div.style.width = `${width}px`;
```

```css
div{
border:1px solid red;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body,div{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id="yourElement">
</div>
```

A more complex way is to get the screen resolution, calculate the difference of browser and viewport size and substract it from the screen resolution. This might give you an pretty good estimate of what the maximum viewport size might be, but I don't know how robust this is cross platform.

I know you might have reasons to try to do this, but you should take a step back, if this is really a good or necessary way to solve your problem.

Comment: But if i load the page with my browser not fully extended it will calculate that size

Comment: This is correct. And there is no other option to do it. About what reference size are we talking anyway, if not the browsers initial size - some imaginary "this would be the maximum size your viewport could be"? Maybe you might want to rethink your whole approach. As webdeveloper you have to learn to adapt to the user. A lot of people don't run browsers in full screen and also don't want to be forced to use them in a way the webdeveloper wants them to.

Answer (score 0):

First set the height of the `<div>` with CSS viewport height (`vh`). Do this in the CSS so that it will be the correct height on page load.

```
div.fullheight {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Then use jQuery to take this height in pixels and reapply it as the height CSS.

```
$('div.fullheight').css('height', $('div.fullheight').height());
```